# simplify if else statement

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I  have some  functionality dependent on many conditions. All variables in conditional statements are boolean variables and the code is the following and I don't like it:

```
    if (userHasMoreThanOneMarket && isOnlyMarketSelected || !userHasMoreThanOneMarket && userHasMoreThanOneAgency) {
        if (isOnlyAgencySelected) {
            //do case 1

        } else if (noAgencySelected && isOnlyMarketSelected) {
            //do case 2
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it more understandable and nice?

Comment: ...if you could add complete code.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me, no obvious redundancies.

Comment: I'm not sure what cleaner code looks like here without knowing how those variables are being defined

Comment: Don't mix AND and OR without using parens - even though it's not required, it helps with readability.

Answer (score 2):

That's about as concise as you're going to get with JavaScript. I suppose if you really wanted to, you could create variables to store your binary options:

```
var multiMarketOneSelected = userHasMoreThanOneMarket && isOnlyMarketSelected;
var singleMarketMultiAgency = !userHasMoreThanOneMarket && userHasMoreThanOneAgency;

if (multiMarketOneSelected || singleMarketMultiAgency) {
    if (isOnlyAgencySelected) {
        //do case 1

    } else if (noAgencySelected && isOnlyMarketSelected) {
        //do case 2
    }
}
```

Though I don't really know if you gain much readability from that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, but if you don't like it you could do something like this (note that the only improvement here is style, if you like it better):

```
function check(){
    return {
        valid: userHasMoreThanOneMarket && isOnlyMarketSelected || !userHasMoreThanOneMarket && userHasMoreThanOneAgency,
        case: [
           isOnlyAgencySelected,
           noAgencySelected && isOnlyMarketSelected
        ]
    };
}

var conditions = check();
if (conditions.valid) {
    if (conditions.case[0]) {
        //do case 1
    } else if (conditions.case[1]) {
        //do case 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things I would try to  make the code more readable:

1. Initialise the variables in a way that you don't have to negate them again. So `!userHasMoreThanOneMarket` becomes `userHasOneMarket`
2. `isOnlyMarketSelected` sounds redundant to me. And you are checking it in the outer if-clause and the inner again.
3. You probably have a lot of code above this code snippet to initialise and set all this boolean values. Try `return;` statements after each variable to get rid of if-conditions.

I hope this helps.